# Jarque-Bera Test for Normal Distrbances in a VAR

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, econometrics, normality-assumption, vector-autoregression

[image]

I did the test of he null hypothesis of Normal disturbances and found that it is rejected for Dlop and Dunp. Does this mean that I have a problem with my model specification? Or how can I rectify this issue?

I have 148 observations using quarterly data spanning from 1980Q1 to 2016Q4. As far as my VAR is concerned. Variable: ln(GDP), ln(Oil Prices), ln(Exchange rates), Inflation Rate (%) and Unemployment Rate (%). All variables differenced to induce stationarity and based on information criteria, they are based on 5 lags for each equation.

Comment: It would help if you mention if you're forecasting or building a structural VAR, state how many observations you have, and write down your VAR system of equations.

Comment: Can you please add this new information as an edit to the original post (OP)?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I would advise you to redirect your attention from the Jarque-Bera test to the specification of your VAR model. Each of the VAR equations will be estimated by OLS. Each of these OLS equations will contain 1+5*5=26 predictors. There is a rule of thumb that you need at least 10 observations per predictor. With 148 observations, you might be pushing this VAR model too far. Chances are that you don't need 5 lags for each variable. How did you determine that 5 lags was appropriate? You might not even need to forecast all 5 variables.

Comment: Keep in mind that your 5 equations need not all have the same lag order.